# Cassandra wide row versus regular row

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I need some help with data modelling for Cassandra.
Here is the problem description:
I have 3 servers processing user requests NodeA,NodeB and NodeC. I have a 1000 different developers ( potentially 10000 ) and must maintain a $ balance for each of them per processing node. 
I can see 2 ways of modeling this:
**1) CF with developerid+balanceid as the row key.** The column names will be NodeA, NodeB and NodeC.

```
create table {
     developerBalanceid int primarykey;
     nodeA varchar;
     nodeB varchar;
     nodeC varchar;
}
```

**2) CF with wide rows with node ids as keys.** The column name will be developerid+balanceid. This seems similar to time-series data being stored in Cassandra.

```
create table {
       nodeid varchar as primary key;
       developerBalanceid int; //this will be dynamic columns
}
```

**Operations:**
**a) Writes:** Every 5 seconds , every node will update the $ balance for every developer. More specifically, at every time t+5, node A will write 1000 balance values. node B will write a 1000 balance values and node C too.

**b) Reads:** Reads also occur every 5 seconds to read a specific developerBalance.

It appears 2) is the best way to model this. 
I do have some concerns about how wide rows will work with the query I want to do. 
In the worst case , what is the number of iops that a wide row read will incur.
Should I be looking at other optimizations like compression on the writes?

I understand that I can run some tests and examine performance. But I would like to hear other experiences too.

Answer (score 1):

The essential rule when modeling with Cassandra is "model from your queries". The main argument in your question is:

> read a specific developerBalance.

If you query by developerBalance, then developerBalance must be the beginning of your primary key. Your solution 1 is better to me.

With the solution 2 you won't be able to write

```
select * from my_table where developerBalanceid=?
```

... without scanning the whole cluster

You must understand what Cassandra querying can not do, what are [partition key and cluster key](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/07/24/understanding-how-cql3-maps-to-cassandras-internal-data-structure/). [Another link](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Quintana. And the Cassandra rules link too. That is really useful!